# The waitpid() parameters

Tags: c, linux, process

I have a question about the waitpid parameters.
I'm supposed to start p[1] (process 1) when p[0] is done.

This is what starts p0:

```
if(p[0] == 0){
    process(0,1); //(process, duration(time))
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want p1 to start as soon as p0 ends (after 1 sec)

```
if(p[1] == 0){
    process(1,2);
    return 0;
}
waitpid(p[0], NULL, 0);
```

Here's my question: what do the parameters in waitpid mean? should the last parameter be set to 1, since p[0] ends after 1 sec and this is when I want p[1] to start?

Comment: Please read the fine manual: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html

Answer (score 4):

> what does the parameters in waitpid means?

You can look up the manual of [`waitpid(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid) for the meanings of its arguments.

In your case,

```
waitpid(p[0], NULL, 0);
```

means

- `p[0]`: wait for the pid hold on `p[0]`
- `NULL`: don't care about status
- `0`: no flags

> should the last parameter be set to 1, since p[0] ends after 1 sec and this is when I want p[1] to start?

To achieve your goal, starting process 1 as soon as process 0 ends, you should put the `waitpid(...);` statement before the `fork()` used to create process 1, and use right parameters in your call to `waitpid()`.

Comment: The linked docs do not explain about the system call options.

Comment: @MatheusSantana I double checked, it explained all the three arguments of `waitpid()`.

Comment: Did it explain that "giving 0 means you are specifying no flags" (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092088/the-waitpid-parameters/22092414?noredirect=1#comment85574455_22092772))? I was troubled with this because I thought `0` could be the value for some flag and I couldn't fetch an answer for this from the man page.

Comment: @MatheusSantana I believe it did, "The options argument is constructed from the bitwise-inclusive OR of zero or more of the following flags", so zero means no extra options.

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted a change suggestion. Another question: do you think waitpid(3) is a better source than waitpid(2) for this case?

Comment: @MatheusSantana  It's hard to say, however, if I was facing the same question, I will reference both of them, and always keep in mind the general rule: information in section three is less system-specific compared to section two.  BTW, thanks for your edition suggestion, it makes the answer clearer.

Comment: and what about the flags? I went to the link provided by @MatheusSantana, but I would expected a more complex answer. If you could also say some about 3rd parameter it would be grate! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Full documentation is on the manpage or here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid

Basically you have 3 parameters:

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

`pid` is the process you are waiting for. Unless you are waiting for multiple children (in which case specify 0, -1, or a number less than -1 - details in the manpage), specify the `pid` of your process here.

`status` is a pointer to an integer which will be filled in with the exit status. This is a combination of the process's exit status and a description of how it has (or has not) exited. The manpage gives you macros you can use to understand this.

`options` can be filled in with a number of flags, `or`ed together. The most useful of these is the somewhat oddly named `W_NOHANG`, which makes `waitpid` simply tell you whether the process has finished (and if so what its exit status was) rather than wait for it to finish.

Comment: But what does it mean giving a `0` value for the `options` parameter?

Comment: Giving 0 means you are specifying no flags (e.g. not `W_NOHANG`, and also no others)

Answer (score 1):

It's used generally to wait until a specific process finishes (or otherwise changes state if you're using special flags), based on its process ID (otherwise known as a `pid`).

It can also be used to wait for any of a group of child processes, either one from a specific process group or any child of the current process.

for example

```
pid_t child_pid;
int status;

child_pid = fork();

if (child_pid == 0) {
     // in child; do stuff including perhaps exec
} else if (child_pid == -1) {
     // failed to fork 
} else {
     if (waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0) == child_pid) {
          // child exited or interrupted; now you can do something with status
     } else {
          // error etc
     }
 }
```

No regarding to parameter in `waitpid` is as follows

**first argument: pid_t pid**

It is the pid of process for which you Wait for the process to exit

**second argument :  int *status**

it is the current status of the program, you can use the macros to test for each condition, such as WIFEXITED , WIFSIGNALED

**Third argument: int options**

The options argument should be 0. You are not required to implement any options. (However, your system should check to make sure that options you do not support are not requested.)

Comment: But what does it mean giving a `0` value for the `options` parameter?